# Asp.net print page

Tags: asp.net, printing

I wont to create a print preview asp.net web page.

Can  any one help me with an example how these should be done?

Comment: I think it is similar or duplicate to [Generate print preview of a web page in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203199/generate-print-preview-of-a-web-page-in-asp-net)

Comment: I think it is similar or duplicate to [Generate print preview of a web page in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203199/generate-print-preview-of-a-web-page-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

a preview for print page should be just like the page you want to print minus stuff that "heavy" for print like images and stuff like that.

you can open a pop up windows of the same window but maybe send a parameter in the query string that tells the page it needs to be in printable version

then just creat a function on the page that makes every "heavy" elemnt visible=false

then you will have a printable version without much work.