# Printing the contents of a div in IE

Tags: c#, javascript, css, internet-explorer

Ok so for some reason my div prints out the way it should in Firefox and Chrome but then when I go to IE it doesnt work. It only prints out one page of the div then the header and footer. I have tried adding some new code to see if I can get it to work better but still having issues. The current code does print out fine but doesnt inherit the divs styling that they had on the page and not in an external style sheet. The commented out code below is what they had there before. Does anyone have any help?

```
    function buildPrint() {

        var sourceDiv = document.getElementById("display_div");
        var WindowObject = window.open('', 'print_div', 'width=750,height=650,top=50,left=50,toolbars=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,resizable=yes');
        WindowObject.document.writeln(sourceDiv.innerHTML);
        WindowObject.document.close();
        WindowObject.focus();
        WindowObject.print();
        WindowObject.close();

        //document.getElementById("print_div").innerHTML = sourceDiv.innerHTML;
        //window.print();

    }
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyPlaceHolder" runat="server">
<div id="display_div">
<asp:CheckBox ID="showAllOptionals" runat="server" Text="Show All Optionals" AutoPostBack="true" />
<asp:Literal ID="mainTable" runat="server" />
</div>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="PrintContent" runat="server">
<div id="print_div" style="page-break-after:avoid;">
</div>

</input><input onclick=\"buildPrint();\" id=\"printBtn\" type=\"button\" value=\"Print\">
```

Comment: In my experience, printing in IE is very buggy. It is best to open content in new window, then call print() on that new window.

Comment: here are a few links that you can look at 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203199/generate-print-preview-of-a-web-page-in-asp-net
the second link should allow you to do what you are trying to do using javascript - http://boardreader.com/thread/print_div_contents_in_javascript_oy3hwX4mzp2.html

Comment: This is a client-side question, so please leave out the server-side code.

Comment: I got the solution, I had to add different CSS to it so the div overflowed and printed. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution, I had to add different CSS to it so the div overflowed and printed. Thanks for all the help