# Print Preview in web browser asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate print preview of a web page in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203199/generate-print-preview-of-a-web-page-in-asp-net)

I have created normal asp.net page to print out task detail. I have print style but my problem how can I make the Print Preview open in Web browser when user click print can someone help me

```
protected void lb_printTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string taskID = Request.QueryString["taskID"];
    Response.Redirect("~/WebForm1.aspx?taskID=" + taskID);
}
```

Comment: Have a look [Creating print preview page dynamically in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13795/Creating-print-preview-page-dynamically-in-ASP-NET)

Comment: Its bacially you to get an idea!!! not to do the same thing. And why don't you have `c#` tag in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Ok Find the solution when your

1. Create print.aspx page
2. user Jquery to open page in Print Preview

   $(document).ready(function () {
       window.print();
   });